# sql server update query with java netbeans

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

i have a serious problem with my app.when i login everything goes well from the connection with the database to retrieving information.but when i want to modify my login password i can't.i don't want why,and when i connect to phpmyadmin everything is great !! please help !

```
try{
         Connection con=null;
           Statement stmt=null;
           ResultSet rs=null;  
           int m=0;
    Class.forName( "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=fiche_de_poste;user=sa;password=admin");
          stmt = con.createStatement();

           rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from compte");

     while(rs.next()){
       String hh=jPasswordField2.getText();
       String hh2=jPasswordField3.getText();
     if(jTextField1.getText().equals(rs.getString("Ncompte"))&&jPasswordField1.getText().equals(rs.getString("Cle"))&&(jPasswordField2.getText().length()>0)&&(jPasswordField3.getText().length()>0)&&(hh.equals(hh2))){
         m=1;
     try{Connection conMOD2=null;
           Statement stmtMOD2=null;
           ResultSet rsMOD2=null;  

Class.forName(                                                                                                                                                                                                     
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");System.out.println("1");




conMOD2=DriverManager.getConnection("same as the previous one"); 
System.out.println("1");  
stmtMOD2 = conMOD2.createStatement();
System.out.println("1");
String reqq="Update compte set Cle='"+jPasswordField3.getText()+"' WHERE      
Ncompte='"+jTextField1.getText()+"'";
System.out.println("2");
System.out.println(reqq);
PSUpdate = conMOD2.prepareStatement(reqq);
PSUpdate.executeUpdate();
//rsMOD2=stmtMOD2.executeQuery(reqq);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Mot de passe modifié avec succès         

!!");

    }catch(Exception ex){}    



        }

     }
     if (m==0)
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID ou mot de passe non valide,ou bien un des champs es vide");
    }catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ops , Impossible de se connecter à la base de données !");
    }
```

Comment: Beautify (format) the code before posting. And what is the line "conMOD2=DriverManager.getConnection("same as the previous one"); " do you really have it in your code? What error message you get?

Comment: no,i have one like the previous one.i had problems with posting this is why i deleted it ;)

Comment: In the SQL UPDATE there was an error. Field Ncompte is of type Text. Text fields cannot be compared using operator "=". Change sql query to  `UPDATE compte SET Cle = ? WHERE Ncompte LIKE ?` . See the answer below that illustrates working solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working solution for your problem. If your data is put in databases: fiche_de_poste and fiche_de_poste2:

In database fiche_de_poste is a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[compte](
    [Cle] [text] ,
    [NCompte] [text]
)
```

In database fiche_de_poste2 create a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[compte](
    [Cle] [text],
    [NCompte] [text]
)
```

And there is data in table `fiche_de_poste.dbo.compte`

|Cle | NCompte |

cle1    compte1

cle2    compte2

data in table `fiche_de_poste2.dbo.compte`

|Cle | NCompte |

cle1    compte1

cle2    compte2

Compile and run the application. When application window appears enter data to fields:

In field "Compte" enter text "compte1"

In field "Cle precedent" enter text "cle1"

In field "Cle nouveau" enter text "cle3"

In field "Cle nouveau" enter text "cle3"

You should see a following image:

[image]

Click a button "Changer cle".

The solution itself:

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JavaApplication1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                BoxLayout bl = new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
                contentPane.setLayout(bl);

                final JTextField jTextField1 = new JTextField();
                final JPasswordField jPasswordField1 = new JPasswordField();
                final JPasswordField jPasswordField2 = new JPasswordField();
                final JPasswordField jPasswordField3 = new JPasswordField();

                Box b = new Box(BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
                b.add(new JLabel("Compte"));
                b.add(jTextField1);
                contentPane.add(b);

                b = new Box(BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
                b.add(new JLabel("Cle précédent"));
                b.add(jPasswordField1);
                contentPane.add(b);

                b = new Box(BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
                b.add(new JLabel("Cle nouveau"));
                b.add(jPasswordField2);
                contentPane.add(b);

                b = new Box(BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
                b.add(new JLabel("Cle nouveau (répété)"));
                b.add(jPasswordField3);
                contentPane.add(b);

                JButton but = new JButton("Changer cle");
                contentPane.add(but);
                but.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Connection con = null;
                            Statement stmt = null;
                            ResultSet rs = null;
                            int m = 0;
                            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=fiche_de_poste");
                            stmt = con.createStatement();

                            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from compte");

                            while (rs.next())
                            {
                                String hh = jPasswordField2.getText();
                                String hh2 = jPasswordField3.getText();
                                if (jTextField1.getText().equals(rs.getString("Ncompte"))
                                        && jPasswordField1.getText().equals(rs.getString("Cle"))
                                        && jPasswordField2.getText().length() > 0
                                        && jPasswordField3.getText().length() > 0
                                        && hh.equals(hh2))
                                {
                                    m = 1;
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=fiche_de_poste2");

                                        String reqq = "UPDATE compte SET Cle = ? WHERE Ncompte LIKE ?";
                                        PreparedStatement ps = con2.prepareStatement(reqq);
                                        ps.setString(1, jPasswordField3.getText());
                                        ps.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());

                                        int rowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
                                        String msg = String.format("%d rangées mise à jour", rowsUpdated);
                                        if (0 < rowsUpdated)
                                        {
                                            msg = msg + " Mot de passe modifié avec succès.";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            msg = msg + " Mot de passe ne modifié pas.";
                                        }
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
                                    }
                                    catch (SQLException sqlex)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("SQL exception message " + sqlex.getMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (m == 0)
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID ou mot de passe non valide,ou bien un des champs es vide");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (SQLException es)
                        {
                            es.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ops , Impossible de se connecter à la base de données !");
                        } 
                    }
                });

                f.setContentPane(contentPane);

                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u bro,but it is not about the same connection.i don't know really wxhat is going on

Comment: okkk okk sppokiii i got it now u used rowsupdated as int...... i'll try and let u know

Comment: ok, rowsupdated is from the result of executeUpdate (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate() ).

Comment: pffff,still not working !! it is not working just in the line :int rowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();

Comment: sure it didn't work. We had a prepared statement, must set values for it. :/ Added code         String reqq = "UPDATE compte SET Cle = ? WHERE Ncompte = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con2.prepareStatement(reqq);
                    ps.setString(1, jPasswordField3.getText());
                    ps.setInt(   2, Integer.valueOf(jTextField1.getText()));. See the updated code.

Comment: still not working :( here is my database     Ncompte:text and Cle:text

Comment: Since they are Text fields both fields must be set with setString. Changed the code to                     ps.setString(1, jPasswordField3.getText());
                    ps.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());

Comment: even ,not working !! i think my reqq is good to be translated to sql serve r

Comment: there is no error message,i'm putting system.out.println("")to see where the program is stopping and it just stop when it come to executeUpdate